# How large does a subgroup of $PSL(2,k)$ need to be in order to have trivial centralizer?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

Let $k$ be a commutative ring, and let $G\le PSL(2,k)$ a subgroup.

How large does $G$ have to be in order that its centralizer in either

1. $PSL(2,k)$, or
2. $PGL(2,k)$

to be trivial? In particular I'm interested in the case where $k$ is a finite field.

Is it sufficient that the corresponding representation of $G$ be irreducible?

Comment: No, irreducibility is not sufficient, it would need to be absolutely irreducible. When $k$ is a field, then the subgroups of ${\rm PGL}(2,k)$ are "known" and easily describable, so the questino could be answered precisely.

Comment: @DerekHolt Aha! Great! Do you have a reference or an argument?